# Handling a situation that implies a bug in the code

Tags: swift

The context for this question is watchkit, but it should be more generally applicable to Swift.

I have a segue from a table in the main interface controller to a second interface controller with a picker. The picker is populated with values based on which table row was chosen. The index of the chosen row `rowIndex` is passed in the context of the awake method (example simplified):

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    guard
        let context = context as? (delegate: InterfaceController, taskModel: TaskModel, rowIndex: Int),
        (context.rowIndex == 0 || context.rowIndex == 1)
    else {
        return //something wrong with the context
    }

    switch rowIndex {
    case 0:
        selection = roleOrTask.role
        pickerOptions = taskModel.roles //copy entries in case data model changed by another object
        setupPicker(options: pickerOptions, preselection: taskModel.currentRole)
    case 1:
        selection = roleOrTask.task
        pickerOptions = taskModel.tasks
        setupPicker(options: pickerOptions, preselection: taskModel.currentTask)
    default:
        return //rowIndex out of bounds
    }

}
```

If either of the two return statements are reached, it implies there is a bug in the code. The awake method assigns values to properties of the interface controller that are implictly unwrapped. Returning early will therefore cause the program to crash when the optional properties are used.

What should the application do when a condition implies the code is broken?

Comment: If the return statements are due to programming errors or an incorrect storyboard the app should crash with FatalError so that this gets discovered during development or testing. Once the app is released an error should be thrown and the app should notify the user that an irrecoverable error has occurred and exit

Comment: FYI - This question is generally applicable to any programming language, not just Swift.